# jpa one to one mapping bidirectional xml issue

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Getting below issue for the below one to one mapping, can you please tell me what is the issue?

```
Exception Description: 
         The join-column element definition for attribute 
        [public com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.ContinuityItem com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.BackendOffer.getContinuityItem()] from the entity class [class com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.BackendOffer] is incomplete.  
     When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a join-column element must be specified for each join column.  Both the name   and the referenced-column-name attributes must be specified in each such join-column.
```

The issue occurring with the one-to-one maping

```
       com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.ContinuityItem, com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.BackendOffer
```

--

```
   <entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.Offer">
        <table name="S_OFFERS" />
        <named-query name="offersByStatus">
            <query>SELECT o FROM Offer o WHERE o.status=:status</query>
        </named-query>
        <named-query name="getAllOffers">
            <query>SELECT o FROM Offer o ORDER BY o.lastUpdateDate DESC</query>
        </named-query>
        <named-query name="getOffersByProductLine">
            <query>SELECT o FROM Offer o WHERE o.productLineCode =
                :productLineCode AND NOT o.status = :excludeStatus</query>
        </named-query>
        <named-query name="getOfferByOfferCode">
            <query>SELECT o FROM Offer o WHERE o.code = :code</query>
        </named-query>
        <entity-listeners>
            <entity-listener class="com.grc.sdb.listener.CodeGeneratorListener">
                <pre-persist method-name="prePersist" />
                <pre-update method-name="preUpdate" />
            </entity-listener>
            <entity-listener class="com.grc.sdb.listener.BeanChangeActivityListener">
                <pre-persist method-name="prePersist" />
                <post-persist method-name="postPersist" />
                <pre-remove method-name="preRemove" />
                <pre-update method-name="preUpdate" />
                <post-update method-name="postUpdate" />
            </entity-listener>
        </entity-listeners>
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <column name="OFFER_ID" />
                <generated-value generator="seqOffers" strategy="SEQUENCE" />
                <sequence-generator name="seqOffers"
                    sequence-name="SEQ_OFFERS" allocation-size="1" />
            </id>
            <basic name="code">
                <column name="OFFER_CODE" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="status">
                <column name="status" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="description">
                <column name="OFFER_DESCRIPTION" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="beginDate">
                <column name="begin_date" />
                <temporal>DATE</temporal>
            </basic>
            <basic name="endDate">
                <column name="end_date" />
                <temporal>DATE</temporal>
            </basic>
            <basic name="creationDate">
                <column name="creation_date" />
                <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
            </basic>
            <basic name="createdBy">
                <column name="created_by" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="currencyCode">
                <column name="currency_code" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="productLineCode">
                <column name="product_line_code" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="clubTypeCode">
                <column name="club_type_code" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="lastUpdatedBy">
                <column name="last_updated_by" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="firstOrderRushAvailableFlag">
                <column name="FIRST_RUSH_AVAILABLE_FLAG" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="firstOrderRushAmount">
                <column name="FIRST_RUSH_AMOUNT" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="firstOrderRushMethod">
                <column name="FIRST_RUSH_METHOD_CODE" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="mpgCode">
                <column name="MPG_CODE" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="contTable">
                <column name="CONT_TABLE_CODE" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="edsKeyCode">
                <column name="EDS_KEY_CODE" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="availableForCanada">
                <column name="FIRST_CANADA_AVAILABLE_FLAG" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="legacyType">
                <column name="LEGACY_OFFER_TYPE" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="continuityKey">
                <column name="CONTINUITY_KEY" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="ffcCode">
                <column name="FFC_CODE" />
            </basic>
            <version name="lastUpdateDate">
                <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
            </version>
            <one-to-many name="orderItems" target-entity="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.OfferItem"
                mapped-by="offer" fetch="LAZY">
                <join-column name="offer_id" referenced-column-name="offer_id" />
                <cascade>
                    <cascade-all />
                </cascade>
            </one-to-many>
            <embedded name="firstOrderDetail">
                <attribute-override name="numPayments">
                    <column name="FIRST_NUM_PAYMENTS" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="numSHPayments">
                    <column name="FIRST_SHIP_NUM_PAY" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="firstPaymentAmount">
                    <column name="FIRST_PAYMENT" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="firstSHAmount">
                    <column name="FIRST_SHIP_HAND" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="addlPaymentAmount">
                    <column name="FIRST_ADDL_PAYMENT" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="addlSHAmount">
                    <column name="FIRST_ADDL_SHIP_HAND" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="canadaSHAmount">
                    <column name="FIRST_CANADA_SHIP_HAND" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="shipMethod">
                    <column name="FIRST_SHIP_HAND_METHOD_CODE" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="shipInterval">
                    <column name="FIRST_CONT_SHIP_INTERVAL" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="payTable">
                    <column name="FIRST_PAYTABLE" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="billingInterval">
                    <column name="FIRST_BILLING_INTERVAL" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="totalPaymentAmount">
                    <column name="FIRST_SHIP_UNIT_PRICE" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="paymentPlanId">
                    <column name="FIRST_OMX_PLAN_ID" />
                </attribute-override>
            </embedded>
            <embedded name="contOrderDetail">
                <attribute-override name="numPayments">
                    <column name="CONT_NUM_PAYMENTS" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="numSHPayments">
                    <column name="CONT_SHIP_NUM_PAY" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="firstPaymentAmount">
                    <column name="CONT_FIRST_PAYMENT" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="firstSHAmount">
                    <column name="CONT_FIRST_SHIP_HAND" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="addlPaymentAmount">
                    <column name="CONT_ADDL_PAYMENT" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="addlSHAmount">
                    <column name="CONT_ADDL_SHIP_HAND" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="canadaSHAmount">
                    <column name="CONT_CANADA_SHIP_HAND" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="shipMethod">
                    <column name="CONT_SHIP_HAND_METHOD_CODE" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="shipInterval">
                    <column name="CONT_SHIP_INTERVAL" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="payTable">
                    <column name="CONT_PAYTABLE" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="billingInterval">
                    <column name="CONT_BILLING_INTERVAL" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="totalPaymentAmount">
                    <column name="CONT_SHIP_UNIT_PRICE" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="paymentPlanId">
                    <column name="CONT_OMX_PLAN_ID" />
                </attribute-override>
            </embedded>
            <transient name="firstOrderItems" />
            <transient name="contOrderItems" />
        </attributes>
    </entity>

    <entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.OfferItem">
        <table name="S_OFFER_ITEMS" />
        <named-query name="removeOfferItems">
            <query>DELETE FROM OfferItem oi WHERE oi.offer.id=:offer_id</query>
        </named-query>
        <named-query name="getOfferItem">
            <query>SELECT oi FROM OfferItem oi WHERE oi.offer.id=:offer_id AND
                oi.code=:item_code</query>
        </named-query>
        <named-query name="getOfferItems">
            <query>SELECT oi.orderType, oi.code, oi.startCode FROM OfferItem oi
                WHERE oi.offer.id=:offer_id</query>
        </named-query>
        <named-query name="getOfferItemsByType">
            <query>SELECT oi FROM OfferItem oi WHERE oi.offer.id=:offer_id AND
                oi.orderType=:order_type</query>
        </named-query>
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <column name="OFFER_ITEM_ID" />
                <generated-value generator="seqOfferItemId"
                    strategy="SEQUENCE" />
                <sequence-generator name="seqOfferItemId"
                    sequence-name="SEQ_OFFER_ITEM_ID" allocation-size="1" />
            </id>
            <basic name="offerId">
                <column name="OFFER_ID" insertable="false" updatable="false" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="code">
                <column name="ITEM_CODE" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="orderType">
                <column name="SHIPMENT_NO" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="createdBy">
                <column name="CREATED_BY" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="creationDate">
                <column name="CREATION_DATE" />
                <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
            </basic>
            <basic name="lastUpdatedBy">
                <column name="LAST_UPDATED_BY" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="lastUpdateDate">
                <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="startCode">
                <column name="START_ITEM_CODE" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="webCartTitle">
                <column name="WEB_CART_TITLE" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="webCartText">
                <column name="WEB_CART_TEXT" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="webCartMaxQty">
                <column name="WEB_CART_MAX_QTY" />
            </basic>

            <many-to-one name="offer">
                <join-column name="OFFER_ID" nullable="false"
                    insertable="true" updatable="true" />
            </many-to-one>
            <transient name="description" />
            <transient name="sequenceNumber" />
            <transient name="webCartTextOverridden" />
            <transient name="resetWebCartText" />
            <transient name="webCartTextUpdated" />

        </attributes>
    </entity>

    <entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.Item">
        <table name="S_ITEMS" />
        <named-query name="getItemByCode">
            <query>SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.status=:status AND
                i.orgCode=:org_code AND i.code=:code</query>
        </named-query>
        <named-query name="getItemByCodeAnyStatus">
            <query>SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.orgCode=:org_code AND
                UPPER(i.code)=:code</query>
        </named-query>
        <named-query name="searchItemsForProductLineByCode">
            <query>SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.status=:status AND
                i.orgCode=:org_code AND i.productLineCode=:product_line_code AND
                UPPER(i.code) LIKE :code_filter ORDER BY i.code</query>
        </named-query>
        <named-query name="searchItemsForContinuity">
            <!-- not checking for status because we want any the Item related to the 
                Continuity even if Inactive -->
            <query>
                SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.orgCode=:org_code
                AND i.code IN
                (SELECT coi.contItemCode FROM ContinuityItem coi WHERE
                coi.continuityKey=:continuityKey)
            </query>
        </named-query>
        <named-query name="countItemsForProductLineByCode">
            <query>SELECT COUNT(i) FROM Item i WHERE i.status=:status AND
                i.orgCode=:org_code AND i.productLineCode=:product_line_code AND
                UPPER(i.code) LIKE :code_filter</query>
        </named-query>
        <attributes>
            <id name="code">
                <column name="item_code" />
            </id>
            <basic name="description">
                <column name="item_description" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="productLineCode">
                <column name="product_line_code" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="orgCode">
                <column name="org_code" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="company">
                <column name="company" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="edsProductNumber">
                <column name="eds_product_no" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="status">
                <column name="item_status" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="invOrg">
                <column name="inv_org" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="invSeq">
                <column name="inv_seq" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="opUnit">
                <column name="op_unit" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="sequenceNumber">
                <column name="SEQ_NUM" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="mnShippingStatusCode">
                <column name="MN_SHIP_STATUS_CODE" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="mnShippingReadinessFlag">
                <column name="MN_SHIP_READINESS_FLAG" />
                <enumerated>STRING</enumerated>
            </basic>
            <basic name="supplySize">
                <column name="SUPPLY_SIZE" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="productDescription1">
                <column name="PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION_1" />
            </basic>
        </attributes>
    </entity>

    <entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.payment.PaymentPlan">
        <table name="S_OMX_PAYMENT_PLANS" />
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <column name="OMX_PLAN_ID" />
                <generated-value generator="seqPlanId" strategy="SEQUENCE" />
                <sequence-generator name="seqPlanId"
                    sequence-name="SEQ_OMX_PLAN_ID" allocation-size="1" />
            </id>
            <basic name="cID">
                <column name="CID" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="planID">
                <column name="PLAN_ID" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="description">
                <column name="PLAN_DESCRIPTION" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="paymentPlanType">
                <column name="PAYMENT_PLAN_TYPE" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="recurrenceXML">
                <column name="RECURRENCE_XML" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="createdBy">
                <column name="CREATED_BY" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="creationDate">
                <column name="CREATION_DATE" />
                <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
            </basic>
            <basic name="lastUpdatedBy">
                <column name="LAST_UPDATED_BY" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="lastUpdateDate">
                <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
            </basic>
            <one-to-many name="paymentPlanDetails"
                target-entity="com.grc.sdb.beans.payment.PaymentPlanDetail"
                mapped-by="paymentPlan" fetch="EAGER">
                <join-column name="OMX_PLAN_ID" referenced-column-name="OMX_PLAN_ID" />
                <cascade>
                    <cascade-all />
                </cascade>
            </one-to-many>
        </attributes>
    </entity>

    <entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.payment.PaymentPlanDetail">
        <table name="S_OMX_PAYMENT_PLAN_DETAILS" />
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <column name="OMX_PLAN_DETAIL_ID" />
                <generated-value generator="seqPlanDetailId"
                    strategy="SEQUENCE" />
                <sequence-generator name="seqPlanDetailId"
                    sequence-name="SEQ_OMX_PLAN_DETAIL_ID" allocation-size="1" />
            </id>
            <basic name="planID">
                <column name="OMX_PLAN_ID" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="paymentID">
                <column name="PAYMENT_ID" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="delayInDays">
                <column name="DELAY_IN_DAYS" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="fraction">
                <column name="FRACTION" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="includeSH">
                <column name="INCLUDE_SH" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="includeTax">
                <column name="INCLUDE_TAX" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="includeNonPrimaryProduct">
                <column name="INCLUDE_NON_PRIMARY_PRODUCT" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="fixedPaymentAmount">
                <column name="FIXED_PAYMENT_AMOUNT" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="createdBy">
                <column name="CREATED_BY" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="creationDate">
                <column name="CREATION_DATE" />
                <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
            </basic>
            <basic name="lastUpdatedBy">
                <column name="LAST_UPDATED_BY" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="lastUpdateDate">
                <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
            </basic>
            <many-to-one name="paymentPlan">
                <join-column name="OMX_PLAN_ID" nullable="false"
                    insertable="false" updatable="false" />
                <cascade>
                    <cascade-all />
                </cascade>
            </many-to-one>
        </attributes>
    </entity>

    <entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.Continuity">
        <table name="S_CONTINUITIES" />
        <named-query name="getAllContinuityOrders">
            <query>SELECT co FROM Continuity co ORDER BY co.lastUpdateDate DESC,
                co.code ASC</query>
        </named-query>
        <attributes>
            <id name="key">
                <column name="continuity_key" />
                <generated-value generator="seqContinuities"
                    strategy="SEQUENCE" />
                <sequence-generator name="seqContinuities"
                    sequence-name="SEQ_CONTINUITY_KEY" allocation-size="1" />
            </id>
            <basic name="code">
                <column name="continuity_code" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="mpgCode">
                <column name="mpg_code" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="creationDate">
                <column name="creation_date" />
                <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
            </basic>
            <basic name="createdBy">
                <column name="created_by" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="lastUpdatedBy">
                <column name="last_updated_by" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="productLineCode">
                <column name="product_line_code" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="ffcCode">
                <column name="ffc_code" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="firstToContShipInterval">
                <column name="FIRST_CONT_SHIP_INTERVAL" />
            </basic>
            <version name="lastUpdateDate">
                <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
            </version>

            <one-to-many name="items"
                target-entity="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.ContinuityItem" mapped-by="continuity"
                fetch="LAZY">
                <order-by>sequenceNumber ASC</order-by>
                <join-column name="continuity_key"
                    referenced-column-name="continuity_key" />
                <cascade>
                    <cascade-all />
                </cascade>
            </one-to-many>
            <embedded name="detail">
                <attribute-override name="numPayments">
                    <column name="NUM_PAYMENTS" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="numSHPayments">
                    <column name="SHIP_NUM_PAY" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="firstPaymentAmount">
                    <column name="FIRST_PAYMENT" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="firstSHAmount">
                    <column name="FIRST_SHIP_HAND" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="addlPaymentAmount">
                    <column name="ADDL_PAYMENT" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="addlSHAmount">
                    <column name="ADDL_SHIP_HAND" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="canadaSHAmount">
                    <column name="CANADA_SHIP_HAND" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="shipMethod">
                    <column name="SHIP_HAND_METHOD_CODE" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="shipInterval">
                    <column name="SHIP_INTERVAL" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="payTable">
                    <column name="PAYTABLE" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="billingInterval">
                    <column name="BILLING_INTERVAL" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="totalPaymentAmount">
                    <column name="UNIT_PRICE" />
                </attribute-override>
                <attribute-override name="paymentPlanId">
                    <column name="CONT_OMX_PLAN_ID" />
                </attribute-override>
            </embedded>
        </attributes>
    </entity>

    <entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.ContinuityItem">
        <table name="S_ITEM_CONTINUITIES" />
        <attributes>
            <id name="continuityKey">
                <column name="continuity_key" insertable="false" updatable="false" />
            </id>
            <id name="contItemCode">
                <column name="cont_item_code" />
            </id>
            <id name="startItemCode">
                <column name="start_item_code" />
            </id>
            <id name="sequenceNumber">
                <column name="SEQ_NUM" />
            </id>
            <basic name="omxSOCId">
                <column name="OMX_SOC_ID" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="itemContinuityCode">
                <column name="item_continuity_code" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="creationDate">
                <column name="creation_date" />
                <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
            </basic>
            <basic name="createdBy">
                <column name="created_by" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="lastUpdatedBy">
                <column name="last_updated_by" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="productLineCode">
                <column name="product_line_code" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="ffcCode">
                <column name="ffc_code" />
            </basic>
            <version name="lastUpdateDate">
                <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
            </version>
            <many-to-one name="continuity">
                <join-column name="continuity_key" nullable="false"
                    insertable="true" updatable="true" />
            </many-to-one>
            <one-to-one name="backendOffer">
                <join-column name="BACKEND_OFFER_ID" nullable="false"
                    insertable="true" updatable="true" />
                <cascade>
                    <cascade-all />
                </cascade>      
            </one-to-one>
        </attributes>
    </entity>

    <entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.Soc">
        <table name="S_OMX_SOC" />
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <column name="OMX_SOC_ID" />
                <generated-value generator="sequenceSocId" strategy="SEQUENCE" />
                <sequence-generator name="seqSocId"
                    sequence-name="SEQ_OMX_SOC_ID" allocation-size="1" />
            </id>
            <basic name="cid">
                <column name="CID" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="config">
                <column name="CONFIGURATION_ID" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="description">
                <column name="SOC_DESCRIPTION" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="recurrencePattern">
                <column name="OMX_RECURRENCE_PATTERN_ID" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="itemCode">
                <column name="ITEM_CODE" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="discountPercentage">
                <column name="DISCOUNT_PERCENT" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="discountAmount">
                <column name="DISCOUNT_AMOUNT" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="noBackorderFlag">
                <column name="NO_BACKORDER_FLAG" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="active">
                <column name="ACTIVE" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="creationDate">
                <column name="CREATION_DATE" />
                <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
            </basic>
            <basic name="createdBy">
                <column name="CREATED_BY" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="lastUpdatedBy">
                <column name="LAST_UPDATED_BY" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="lastUpdateDate">
                <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
            </basic>
        </attributes>
    </entity>

    <entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.BackendOffer">
        <table name="S_BACKEND_OFFERS" />
        <attributes>
            <id name="backendOfferID">
                <column name="BACKEND_OFFER_ID" />
                <generated-value generator="seqBackendOffers"
                    strategy="SEQUENCE" />
                <sequence-generator name="seqBackendOffers"
                    sequence-name="seq_backend_offer_id" allocation-size="1" />
            </id>           
            <basic name="backendOfferCode">
                <column name="backend_Offer_Code" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="backendOfferDescription">
                <column name="backend_Offer_Description" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="creationDate">
                <column name="creation_date" />
                <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
            </basic>
            <basic name="createdBy">
                <column name="created_by" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="lastUpdatedBy">
                <column name="last_updated_by" />
            </basic>
            <version name="lastUpdateDate">
                <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
            </version>
            <one-to-one name="continuityItem">
                <join-column name="continuity_key"  nullable="false" insertable="true" updatable="true"/>
                <cascade>
                    <cascade-refresh />
                </cascade>
            </one-to-one>           
        </attributes>
    </entity>

    <embeddable class="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.OrderDetail">
        <attributes>
            <basic name="numPayments" />
            <basic name="numSHPayments" />
            <basic name="firstPaymentAmount" />
            <basic name="firstSHAmount" />
            <basic name="addlPaymentAmount" />
            <basic name="addlSHAmount" />
            <basic name="canadaSHAmount" />
            <basic name="shipMethod" />
            <basic name="shipInterval" />
            <basic name="payTable" />
            <basic name="billingInterval" />
            <basic name="totalPaymentAmount" />
            <basic name="paymentPlanId" />
        </attributes>
    </embeddable>

    </entity-mappings>
```

Comment: format your question properly

Comment: if the problem is about just those two classes, and that relation ... perhaps remove the result of the classes so people can focus on just the important part? Also the message says "a join-column element must be specified for each join column", yet you only provide join-column for 1 of the 4 "ContinuityItem" Id fields. So follow what the message says

Comment: You've posted far too much code here, please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the section about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).